# is it mandatory to make Universal App for Keyboard Extension in IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios-universal-app, ios-keyboard-extension

I have developed a keyboard extension for iphone and submitted to Appstore. But it got rejected due to-
2.10: iPhone Apps must also run on iPad without modification, at iPhone resolution, and at 2X iPhone 3GS resolution.

Do I need to make universal App, or just make it scalable up to ipad and submit to App store?

Comment: @Neenu Please be a little more careful about what tags you're adding to the question. In many of the "added a new tag for better response" edits, you fail to correct other issues with the post. Furthermore, the new tags you're adding are often irrelevant, as with the (now rolled-back) edit you made on this post.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make it universal. It only needs to run on the iPad at the iPhone resolution.

SOURCE:  WWDC sessions

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to. As the rejection reason said, if it can run on iPad with iPhone resolution, it's fine.